# webpage image href - small horizontal line

Tags: html, css

For some reason I have a tiny horizontal line to the bottom right of each of my social media images I've placed on a header on my website. I've tried to find an explanation on why they appear and more importantly, how to hide them. Does anyone know how to remove them? Thank you very much.

[image]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title> Chilun</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face /* support for browsers & IE v10 onwards*/
{font-family:homefont; src: url("font.ttf");}
{font-family:headerfont; src: url("playball.ttf");}
body {background:url('img/mybackground3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;}

<!-- Make Header Sticky -->
#header_container {background:#00E5EE; border:0px solid #666; height:70px; left:0; position:fixed; width:100%; top:0;}
#header{padding: 0.3em 0; border-bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; line-height:0px; margin:0 auto; width:940px; text-align:right;display:inline-block; float:right;vertical-align:bottom;}
#wrapper{width:900px;margin:0 auto;}
a{color:#444;}
.logo{margin-left:600px;margin-top:100px;background:#fff;padding:10px;}
.bigtitle{font-family: homefont; font-size:120px; text-align:center; margin-top:200px;}
.header{top:100%; left:50%; font-family: headerfont; font-size:20px; color:#FFFFFF; font-style:italic; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-right:20px; padding-left:0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- BEGIN: Sticky Header -->
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header"><p class="header"> Follow me on:

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/chilunliuTheBOSSE"><img src="/img/facebook-lnk.gif" alt="View my Facebook Profile" width="40" height="40" border="0">
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/+chilunliu/posts/p/pub"><img src="/img/googleplus-lnk.gif" alt="View my Google Plus Profile" width="40" height="40" border="0">

     <a style="margin:0; href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/chilun-liu/1b/297/416"; View my Linkedin Profile </a><img src="/img/linkedin-lnk.gif" width="40" height="40">
    <a style="margin:0; href=""; Email me </a><img src="/img/email-lnk.gif" width="40" height="40">
    <a style="margin:0; href="http://www.youtube.com/user/chilunliu"; View my Youtube Channel</a><img src="/img/youtube-lnk.gif" width="40" height="40">
    </div>
    </p>

</div>
<!-- END: Sticky Header -->

    <div id="wrapper">
      <h2 class="bigtitle">
      <p>
      Chilun
      Liu
      </p>
      </h2>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did one of the answers help you with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing all of the `</a>` closing tags...

Answer (score 0):

```
<a style="margin:0;" href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/chilun-liu/1b/297/416"> View my Linkedin Profile</a> <img src="/img/linkedin-lnk.gif" width="40" height="40">
<a style="margin:0;" href=""> Email me </a><img src="/img/email-lnk.gif" width="40" height="40">
<a style="margin:0;" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/chilunliu"> View my Youtube Channel</a><img src="/img/youtube-lnk.gif" width="40" height="40">
```

this is how your a tags should be closed

Answer (score 0):

Next what all the others says about closing the `<a>` tags with `</a>`. 
 You need to set this in your css.  I had the same problem and `text-decoration: none;` was the solution for me.

**Css**

```
a { text-decoration: none};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the changed tag.

```
<a style="margin:0;" href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/chilun-liu/1b/297/416"> View my Linkedin Profile </a>
<img src="/img/linkedin-lnk.gif" width="40" height="40">
<a style="margin:0;" href=""> Email me </a>
<img src="/img/email-lnk.gif" width="40" height="40">
<a style="margin:0;" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/chilunliu"> View my Youtube Channel</a><img src="/img/youtube-lnk.gif" width="40" height="40">
```

Below is the result of the tag and there is no underline :)

View my Linkedin Profile 
[image]
 Email me 
[image]
 View my Youtube Channel[image]

Hope this helps.